# Mongo: merge subdocuments and reference the parent in a field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following mongo collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("000000000001"),
    "username" : "user1",
    "password" : "password",
    "alerts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5947a8d3b5ac80946b7ee4bd"),
            "direction" : "rise",
            "threshold" : "1000",
            "notified" : true,
            "notified_when" : null
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5947a8d8b5ac80946b7ee4be"),
            "direction" : "rise",
            "threshold" : "1200",
            "notified" : false,
            "notified_when" : null
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("000000000002"),
    "username" : "user2",
    "password" : "password",
    "alerts" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5947a8d3b5ac80946b7ee4bd"),
            "direction" : "rise",
            "threshold" : "1000",
            "notified" : true,
            "notified_when" : null
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("000000000003"),
    "username" : "user3",
    "password" : "password",
    "alerts" : []
}
```

I'd like to select only the `alerts` objects, and merge them together. If possible, I'd like to inject into each of the `alert` the `_id` field of the parent user.

I could do that in plain javascript, but I was wondering whether it was feasible with MongoDB or not.

The result would then be:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5947a8d3b5ac80946b7ee4bd"),
        "direction" : "rise",
        "threshold" : "1000",
        "notified" : true,
        "notified_when" : null,
        "parent_id": ObjectId("000000000001")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5947a8d8b5ac80946b7ee4be"),
        "direction" : "rise",
        "threshold" : "1200",
        "notified" : false,
        "notified_when" : null,
        "parent_id": ObjectId("000000000001")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5947a8d3b5ac80946b7ee4bd"),
        "direction" : "rise",
        "threshold" : "1000",
        "notified" : true,
        "notified_when" : null,
        "parent_id": ObjectId("000000000002")
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it using aggregation. First [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the alerts array and then project the required fields. Unwind deconstructs the array, and returns one document for each array element.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{$unwind: '$alerts'},
{$project:  {
        "_id" : '$alerts._id',
        "direction" : "$alerts.direction",
        "threshold" : "$alerts.threshold",
        "notified" : '$alerts.notified',
        "notified_when" : '$alerts.notified_when',
        "parent_id": '$_id'
    }}
)
```

Comment: That is quite an elegant way of doing; I like it. I didn't know about $unwind and aggregates in general. Thanks a lot !